# python: generate different file number sequence for each function

Tags: python

My task is to process 3 categories of files (each has different function in my original python code) and at end of processing i need to assign sequence number to that file., which is separate to that category.

i tried to put sample code of my requirement, PLEASE PLEASE help me to suggest the best approach to do it.

All files with 'Apple' keyword will end with separate sequence numbering, and same way for other two categories.

```
import shutil

Apple = 1
def AppleNum():
    global Apple
    Apple += 1
    return str(Apple).zfill(3)

Banana = 1
def BananaNum():
    global Banana
    Banana += 1
    return str(Banana).zfill(3)

Orange = 1
def OrangeNum():
    global Orange
    Orange += 1
    return str(Orange).zfill(3)

def List_files(filepath, substr):
    X = Y = []
    for path, subdirs, files in sorted(os.walk(filepath), reverse=True):
        for name in files:
            X.append(os.path.join(path, name))
    if substr == 'AAA':
        return [str for str in Y if any(sub in str for sub in substr) and 'xml' in str]
    elif substr == 'BBB':
        return [str for str in Y if substr in str]
    elif substr == 'CCC':
        return [str for str in Y if substr in str and '.csv' in str]
    else:
        return ""

  def copy_func():
    for file in List_files(test_path, 'AAA'):
      seq = AppleNum()
      shutil.copy(file, 'files/' +str(file) + _ + seq)
    for file in List_files(test_path, 'BBB'):
      seq = BananaNum()
      shutil.copy(file, 'files/' +str(file) + _ + seq)
    for file in List_files(test_path, 'CCC'):
      seq = OrangeNum()
      shutil.copy(file, 'files/' +str(file) + _ + seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    copy_func()
```

`Please help if there is any other best approach to do this, because as per my new requirements 3 categories became 12.`

if input files are as below..

```
Apple_oo.xml
Banana_dsh
Apple_bb.xml
Orange.csv
Orange_dhj.csv
Orange_sk.csv
Banana_dhs
```

Expected Output after assigning sequence numbering:

```
Apple_oo.xml_2
Banana_dsh_2
Apple_bb.xml_3
Orange.csv_2
Orange_dhj.csv_3
Orange_sk.csv_4
Banana_dhs_3
```

Please help me with suggestions..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a `dict` with sequence nums for each type

Comment: `any(sub in str for sub in substr)` will be true if there is an A in the filename - is that the intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a generator to list the filtered file names, and use `enumerate` to create index numbers for each one.

```
import shutil
import os

def filtered_files(path, filters):
    """ List files in the path whose filenames contain the given string filters """
    for p, subdirs, files in sorted(os.walk(path), reverse=True):
        for name in files:
            if all(f in name for f in filters):
                yield os.path.join(p, name)

def make_numbered_copies(files, outfile="{name}_{index:03}", start=0):
    for i, file in enumerate(files, start=start):
        shutil.copy(file, outfile.format(name=file, index=i))

def main():
    filter_groups = [("AAA", "xml"), ("BBB", ), ("CCC", ".csv")]  # add more as needed
    for filters in filter_groups:
        files = filtered_files(path, filters)
        make_numbered_copies(files, outfile="files/{name}_{index:03}", start=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You may need to adapt the `filtered_files` function depending on how complicated your filters are. Consider using [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fnmatch.html) (e.g. `fnmatch(name, "*AAA*.xml")`) or regex for more complicated filters.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It helps.